# How do I customize the Test Result Work Item Template Definition in TFS 2015?

Tags: tfs, tfs-2015

My question is simple: I have used WITAdmin in the past to add custom fields to various work item types in TFS. Most recently - to add time estimates to the Test Case work item template in TFS. However, when I use WitAdmin listwitd command on my project, I don't see anything for Test Result.

Is there any way to customize the work item template for test results in TFS? I want to add an additional test result steps beyond the ones that are already out of the box, i.e. pass, fail, blocked, not applicable.

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is **no work item type which called test result** in TFS.  You can customize the Test Plan & Test suite & Test Case and add custom fields or define custom workflows to it, just without test result.

The test result is associated with MTM. If you want to customize Test Result Failure Type & Resolution Type, please refer the link from MSDN: [Customize and manage the test experience [tcm and Microsoft Test Manager]](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff398070.aspx)

For more info, please take a look at this uservoice: *[Provide customization for test plan, test results](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-team-services/suggestions/2039013-provide-customization-for-test-plan-test-results)*.